# Histogram of a vector

Tags: self-study, histogram

I need to implement an algorithm that plots an histogram of a vector containing N values. Those values are all calculated by an simulation, so, as we can note, we should obtain values like 3.45543 and 3.45520 (for example). So, if I just count the frequency of the values and plot it, I won't have a good result.

I was wondering if the best solution to this problem is to round every number using 1 or 2 digits and count the frequencies (if I round using 1 digit, the numbers above would give me the same result, what is desirable since they are close). Also, I was thinking if the number of elements (N) would be important to guide the number of digits I should use (usually, it is huge)

Comment: Why would you want to do it by hand rather then using an existing software? Also notice that programming questions are off-topic on CV.

Comment: Because it is an assigment. Also, I don't think that my question is about the program I need to write, but if what I am trying to do makes sense statistically.

Comment: It seems to me that the "vector" is just a data type in your software, and is basically equivalent to having a list of data that you need to create a histogram for. (The title suggested to me that you wanted a kind of multi-dimensional histogram, but I see now that this is not the case.) Perhaps you should review your basic understanding of what a "histogram" is - a good high school textbook [or revision site](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/statistics/representingdata3hirev3.shtml) ([alternative](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/histograms.html)) might help you out.

Comment: Just about every text advises bins of equal width unless you have very strong grounds to do otherwise. So, there are two ways to do this: think about what kind of bin width would be sensible or what number of bins would be sensible. Which would be easier for you we can't say. There is lots of guidance on both accessible after a simple search.

Comment: Essentially, histograms display continuous data not by showing the *frequency* of individual pieces of data (it's not uncommon to have a data set with no repeated data at all, as in your case), but the *frequency density* for various *classes* (i.e. intervals or ranges) of data. Both of your examples would lie in a 3.45-3.50 class, for instance, but whether that would be a suitable class to use would depend on your data set. Look up "histogram binning" to see many such discussions on this issue. (I have posted approximately simultaneously with Nick Cox whose advice is also wise.)